# How to Check or Uncheck all Items in VB.NET CheckedListBox Control

Tags: vb.net

I need to select and unselect all items in a VB.NET `CheckedListBox` control, what is the best way to do this?

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        With clbCheckedListBox

        .Items.Add("Select/UnSelect All")
        .Items.Add("Enero")
        .Items.Add("Febrero")
        .Items.Add("Marzo")
        .Items.Add("Abril")
        .Items.Add("Mayo")
        .Items.Add("Junio")
        .Items.Add("Julio")
        .Items.Add("Agosto")
        .Items.Add("Septiembre")
        .Items.Add("Octubre")
        .Items.Add("Noviembre")
        .Items.Add("Diciembre")

        .SelectedIndex = 0

    End With


End Sub


    Private Sub clbCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clbCheckedListBox.ItemCheck

    If e.Index = 0 Then

        If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then

            For idx As Integer = 1 To Me.clbCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1
                Me.clbCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(idx, CheckState.Checked)
            Next

        ElseIf e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked Then

            For idx As Integer = 1 To Me.clbCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1
                Me.clbCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(idx, CheckState.Unchecked)
            Next

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

After Hours the above code work fine for me !

Comment: Please mark the appropriate answer.

Comment: Blech. No enumeration support??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ricardo, perhaps this might be what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim items$() = New String() {"Select/UnSelect All", "Enero",
     "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio",
     "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"}
    For Each Str As String In items : clbCheckedListBox.Items.Add(Str) : Next
End Sub ' Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

Private Sub clbCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clbCheckedListBox.ItemCheck
    If e.Index = 0 Then
        Dim newCheckedState As CheckState = e.NewValue
        For idx As Integer = 1 To clbCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1
            Me.clbCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(idx, newCheckedState)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is marked as the answer, but you're starting at index 1 and SetItemCheckState won't work in any code I've ever worked in, only SetItemChecked works.

Comment: @Keith: yes it intentionally skips the first item because the first item is 'Select/UnSelect All'.

Comment: And i tested that code before i posted it. so i know that code worked for me. Keith, does SetItemCheckState not work for u in WinForms or WPF? I used a WinForm project. i used VS 2010 since in my opinion, the later VS 2012 and 2013 were downgrades. but i don't think the VS version wud matter. I know i used .NET 4 environment (i think .NET 4.5). sometimes that matters with MS quirks. maybe u might want to compare ur environment that doesn't work with SetItemCheckState to my environment.

Comment: @Keith, i do know that if i only want states of checked or unchecked, then i'd prefer to use the SetItemChecked() method that u share works for u. SetItemCheckedState() is for 3 states, not 2: Checked, Unchecked, and Indeterminate. Keith, i wud check 3 things: 1: your environment is WinForms, 2: your control is a `CheckedListBox` and 3: you are using .NET 4.5 or later.

Answer (score 20):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Dim checked As Boolean = True   ' Set to True or False, as required.
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, checked)
Next
```

Here I'm just looping through all the CheckedListBox Items and setting their checked state.

Answer (score 4):

```
If button.Text = "Select All" Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To checklist.Items.Count - 1
        checklist.SetItemChecked(i, True)
    Next
    Button.Text = "Deselect All"
Else
    For i As Integer = 0 To checklist.Items.Count - 1
        checklist.SetItemChecked(i, False)
        Button.Text = "Select All"
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

```
To check all CheckedListBox Item:

For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
     CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, True)
Next

To uncheck all CheckedListBox Item:

For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
     CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false)
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that `clbCheckedListBox.clearSelection()` works well for unselecting all.

Comment: Welcome to SO Trey :-). Generally it is not a great idea to add to questions that are this old and already have an accepted answer. Further, answers are encouraged to write more than just a single line - otherwise maybe a comment would be better. Finally, please try format contributions correctly as it helps with legibility; in this case the code can be formatted (I will go ahead and edit so you see what I mean).

Comment: @Trey You mean `.ClearSelected()`? My VisualStudio 2017 with .NET target framework 4.5 doesn't accept your suggestion. And just for the records: This does NOT uncheck the items, just unselect them.

Answer (score 1):

Added a separate `checkbox` called "Select All". On checking and unchecking of this `checkbox` items of a `checklistbox` can be selected or unselected. So you can call this `Kb()` function anywhere in your code:

```
Private Sub ChkSelectAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChkSelectAll.Click
    Kb(ChkSelectAll.CheckState)
End Sub

Private Sub Kb(ByVal Key As Boolean)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ChkLstServices.Items.Count - 1
        ChkLstServices.SetItemChecked(i, Key)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the **SelectedValueChanged** event.

```
Private Sub clbCheckedListBox_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ContrListCheckBox.SelectedValueChanged
    If clbCheckedListBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        If clbCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(0) = False Then
            For idx As Integer = 1 To clbCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1

                Me.clbCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(idx, False)
            Next
        Else
            For idx As Integer = 1 To ContrListCheckBox.Items.Count - 1

                Me.clbCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(idx, True)
            Next
        End If
    ElseIf clbCheckedListBox.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        If clbCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Count = clbCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1 And clbCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(0) = False Then
            clbCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Checked)
        End If
        For idx As Integer = 1 To clbCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1

            If clbCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(idx) = False Then
                clbCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Unchecked)

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Other solutions are correct but if you want to deselect another checkbox inside the CheckBoxList or empty the CheckBoxList without the `Select All` checkbox
the top checkbox will remain checked and it is not logical so the above code should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to bundle the check/uncheck events - of two buttons, for example - into one handler and use the value of `sender` to set the check state:

```
Private Sub clbCheckedListBox(
    ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAll.Click, btnNone.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To clbApis.Items.Count - 1
        clbApis.SetItemChecked(i, sender Is btnAll)
    Next i
End Sub
```